# Why would a Finder open / launch of an app FAIL, when [NSWorkspace launchApplication] will always work?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging

We have a MacBook Pro with 10.11.3 installed.  We use this machine for testing.  Something has messed with this machine such that one of our legacy Carbon apps will NOT open / launch from the Finder.  The app sits and bounces on the dock but never launches.

However, when launching the exact same app programmatically using [NSWorkspace launchApplication] from a Cocoa registration utility we built, the app will ALWAYS launch.

Attempts to sample this failed launching app using Activity Monitor tend not to reveal anything -- except that it seems the hanging app is usually in a call to a function called "cantTutThis".  Anyone heard of this?

(NOTE: on all our other 10.11.3 systems, we haven't seen this problem)
(NOTE2: no messages appear in Console until unresponsive app has been face quit)

```
Call graph:
    2820 Thread_10759   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 2820 _dyld_start  (in dyld) + 71  [0x8fe06047]
    +   2820 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)  (in dyld) + 427  [0x8fe06231]
    +     2820 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*)  (in dyld) + 3514  [0x8fe0ac47]
    +       2820 dyld::initializeMainExecutable()  (in dyld) + 218  [0x8fe06f7f]
    +         2820 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&)  (in dyld) + 79  [0x8fe14ea1]
    +           2820 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)  (in dyld) + 105  [0x8fe14c41]
    +             2820 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)  (in dyld) + 296  [0x8fe14dae]
    +               2820 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&)  (in dyld) + 64  [0x8fe190a0]
    +                 2820 ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&)  (in dyld) + 291  [0x8fe18f47]
    +                   2820 ???  (in OurCarbonApp)  load address 0x1000 + 0x7f9c24  [0x7fac24]
    +                     2820 ???  (in OurCarbonApp)  load address 0x1000 + 0x7f99b3  [0x7fa9b3]
    +                       2820 NSUnLinkModule  (in libdyld.dylib) + 81  [0x9a151346]
    +                         2820 NSUnLinkModule  (in dyld) + 344  [0x8fe10eae]
    +                           2820 __cxa_finalize_ranges  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 318  [0x91779979]
    +                             2820 ???  (in CantTutThis)  load address 0x25f1000 + 0x2b0aec  [0x28a1aec]
    +                               2820 ???  (in CantTutThis)  load address 0x25f1000 + 0x8912d  [0x267a12d]
    2820 Thread_10773   DispatchQueue_2: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  (serial)
      2820 _dispatch_mgr_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 52  [0x95eee2e2]
        2820 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 234  [0x95eee70e]
          2820 kevent_qos  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x9e123812]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        ???  (in CantTutThis)  load address 0x25f1000 + 0x8912d  [0x267a12d] [STACK TOP]        2820
        kevent_qos  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2820

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x70aff7 +com.writebros.OurCarbonApp (6.2 - 6.2.4.7) <0577AB86-2EC7-3C26-A6DA-B514FFF48D7C> /Applications/MMOurCarbonAppTest/OurCarbonApp.app/Contents/MacOS/OurCarbonApp
 0x25f1000 -  0x2991ff3 +CantTutThis (???) <44557A53-D8E2-33AB-BE43-94283F93AF19> CantTutThis
0x8fe05000 - 0x8fe3958f  dyld (0.0 - ???) <8F9518A3-884D-35FF-8FD9-FB149B7F1BF2> /usr/lib/dyld
(AND LOTS MORE BINARY IMAGES...)
```

Comment: Check the Console application to see if the system is logging any errors at the time it tries to launch your app.

Comment: Nothing is dumped to the Console until after the unresponsive app is forced to quit.

Comment: Search your system for a file with "CantTutThis" in its name. It's some sort of plug-in or hack that's injecting itself into your app process. Might be malware. It's a bit weird that the crash report doesn't show its path.

Comment: I have searched, and searched -- can't find anything with that name! (even searching including System Folders, or course)

Comment: It may be possible to use Spotlight to search for the binary id: "44557A53-D8E2-33AB-BE43-94283F93AF19" (or possibly without hyphens).  It's a long shot but, I mention it because symbolicating a crash uses that id to find an image with symbols.

Comment: Try launching your app from the shell with the `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` environment variable set.  That is, issue the command `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 /Applications/MMOurCarbonAppTest/OurCarbonApp.app/Contents/MacOS/OurCarbonApp`. See if something obvious is logged. Or edit your question to show what is logged.

Comment: From Terminal the program LAUNCHED -- didn't hang, and Terminal reported only this:  "The function 'CGSFlushWindow' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update.  Please use CGSFlushWindowContentRegion instead".     
     
     
 AFTER HANGING ON DOUBLE CLICK, I'VE SEEN THESE IN CONSOLE:

"mdworker: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: error Domain=NSOSStatusErr code = -67062"

"SpotlightNetHelper: tcp_connection_destination_handle_ls_close_notify 43 closing socket due to TLS CLOSE-NOTIFY ALERT"

Comment: Remove the preferences and/or saved application state.

Comment: @Willeke -- for OurCarbonApp?  We've done that dozens of times.  If that were the cause, there should be no difference between double-click launching and launching via Cocoa API...

Comment: First, if/when you respond to someone in comments, it helps to address them (e.g. @SMGreenfield) or they won't be informed (unless you're commenting on their question or answer). When it launched from the shell, it might still have loaded CantTutThis, so the `dyld` output with that environment variable may still be helpful. Are you sure you issued the command like I showed? (It's one command, not two.) Another thing to try: `cd /` before issuing the command.

Comment: @KenThomases -- Still researching this.  I DO get a nice dump of dynamic libraries loaded, but unless I can somehow get the same information during a DOUBLE-CLICK launch of the app, it's not going to help, because a double-click finder launch is the only case where launching the app hangs.

Comment: Just because it doesn't hang doesn't mean the `dyld` output might not indicate where CantTutThis is being loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but new information for context and future Googlers: Is this app protected by Pace's iLok system?

I have a bunch of audio plugins that are iLok-protected, and all of those have the "CantTutThis" reference in - probably as a snarky nod to hackers who try to decrypt the wrapped/encrypted content.

I just had one that crashed on launch, and the crashed plugin was identified as "CantTutThis", presumably as the encrypted contents couldn't be retrieved to report the actual plugin details.